# attach both Google Drive file and sheet PDF to the same email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail

I have the following code

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "yyyy-MM-dd")
      var images = [];
      var searchTerm = date
      var searchFor ="title contains '" + searchTerm + "'"; //single quotes are needed around searchterm
      var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor); 
        while (files.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          images.push(file);
      }
      
      var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent()
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gid="+sheetgId+"&range=A1:AD36&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false&portrait=false&scale=4&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&top_margin=0.50&bottom_margin=0.50&left_margin=0.80&right_margin=0.80";
      
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
        }
      });
      var contents = result.getContent();
      var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(email1,subject ,body, {htmlBody: htmlBody,from: aliases[2], name: "HCA AutoCorreos", attachments:[images,{fileName:"RdP "+date+ ".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]});
```

that should send both PDF created from Spreadsheet and files from Google Drive. Separately it works fine but if I try to combine it it in "attachments" it returns error.
What do I do wrong in the attachments section?

Comment: so, in the last line of your code, you specify one file name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modification point:

- `attachments` is required to be one dimensional array. In your script, `[images,{fileName:"RdP "+date+ ".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]` is used. In this case, `images` is one dimensional array. By this, an error occurs. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When this point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email1,subject ,body, {htmlBody: htmlBody,from: aliases[2], name: "HCA AutoCorreos", attachments:[images,{fileName:"RdP "+date+ ".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application//pdf"}]});
```

To:

```
var attachments = images.concat({fileName:"RdP "+date+ ".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application/pdf"});
GmailApp.sendEmail(email1,subject ,body, {htmlBody: htmlBody,from: aliases[2], name: "HCA AutoCorreos", attachments:attachments});
```

or

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(email1,subject ,body, {htmlBody: htmlBody,from: aliases[2], name: "HCA AutoCorreos", attachments:[...images,{fileName:"RdP "+date+ ".pdf", content:contents, mimeType:"application/pdf"}]});
```

#### Note:

- I think that in this case, you can use `mimeType:"application/pdf"` instead of `mimeType:"application//pdf"`.

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: @Anton Marchuk Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.